# read more script looks nice, not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to include a readmore script in a website.

I tested the script on http://jsfiddle.net/4zL67z6k/ and got a good result for the code.

I have `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` on the first line of the header for my site and I have tested a simple welcome script.

I am not sure why I can't get the read more script to function. Any solutions?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4zL67z6k/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your `this` is the `p` you have clicked on. And you are searching within this `p` fore `.more-content`. But the `.more-conten`t is outside this `p`. So just define a container and let the click handler execute on this container.

Try it with [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and not with find().

Comment: Thanks man. That worked perfectly. Hours on a simple error. The odd thing is, on my site it won't stay open. Here comes a few more hours of putzing with code.

Comment: Good luck ;) Please consider to mark my answer as correct. Thanks